# how to send any function through a channel in golang?

Tags: go

I want to implement an executor like below:

```
type task func()

type executor struct {
    tasks chan task
}

func (e *executor) Push(t task) {
    select {
    case e.tasks <- t:
    default:
        return
    }
}
func (e *executor) Run() {
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-e.tasks:
            t()

        }
    }
}
func (e *executor) Init() {
    e.tasks = make(chan task, 10)
}
```

Then, I want to wrap any function into task type, like this pseudo code:

```
func make_task(f function_addr, args ...interface{}) task{
    return func(){
    f(args...)
}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a really weird thing to want to do. It seems like maybe you're just inventing a layer of abstraction on top of `go func(args)` and a counting semaphore in the form of a buffered channel. What benefit do you gain by sending a function and its arguments over a channel to be invoked by a go routine, when Go gives you the `go` keyword specifically for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach is to use a [function literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_literals) in place of make_task:

```
t := func() { exampleFunction(exampleArg1, exampleArg2) }
e.Push(t)
```

If the simple approach does not fit into your application for some reason, then use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to call an arbitrary function with arbitrary arguments:

```
func make_task(f interface{}, args ...interface{}) task {
    return func() {
        values := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
        for i := range args {
            values[i] = reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
        }
        reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(values)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
func hello(arg string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello", arg)
}

…

t := make_task(hello, "world")
t()  // prints Hello world
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5b6VPfV45qo

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a generic function to do what you want, but you can do what you need using closures like:

```
executor.Push(func() {
    someFunc(arg1,arg2,...)
 })
```

where `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. are arguments available at that point in code.